# Use async/await or Task.Run in a continuous work?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I am confused about whether to use `async/await` or `Task.Run` when encountering continuous long running work. I've read a lot material and examples about asynchronous programming, but most of them are concerned with work whose ending could be predicted. In my application, which is a WPF app with MVVM, main work of the app is doing endless loop in which the time-consuming work lays. The main logic of the work looks like this:

```
// this method is fired by a command which binds to a button
private void OnStart()
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.Start();
        while(IsWorking)
        {
            TimeConsumingWork();
            sw.Stop();
            if (sw.ElapsedMiiliseconds >= 1000)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000 - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                sw.Restart();
            }
        }
     });
}
```

I start/stop the time-consuming work by a toggle button, and the time-consuming work will **loop forever** for a long time(expect 4-30 days). The time-consuming work contains a considerable IO-bound, which is appending a (6-13cols ⨉ 1000-20000rows) data to a csv file per seconds.

So, is it necessary to change `Task.Run` to `async/await` form? It seems like it would be more preferable to use `async/await` rather than `Task.Run`.

Comment: Those things are used *together*. When you use `Task.Run` to start some CPU-bound work you also use `await` to await for it to finish. In fact you should be doing that already instead of firing off a Task that can't be monitored. What if it fails? You should use an asynchronous event handler (`async void` signature) that awaits that task with `Task.Run()`. Instead of blocking, use `await Task.Delay()`, or use a timer to fire the task periodically instead of looping

Comment: If `TimeConsumingWork` is IO bound then I'd suggest making it async and use the appropriate async methods when dealing with the IO and await them.  Then you likely would not need the `Task.Run` at all.

Comment: Maybe you will need specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions

Comment: Use a background `Thread` or like others said use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` which schedules the task to a dedicated `Thread` anyway.

Comment: async/await generally used to execute operations asynchronously. It doesn't matter if this operationis long running or not. Asynchronous just means the UI thread yields back control instead of being blocked. `Task.Run` starts a new thread, a background thread. You can gain some extra performance by pushing long running _ CPU bound_ work to a background thread. _CPU bound!_ You never want to create an extra thread for I/O bound operations like file access or downloading. In this case you must use pure asynchronous methods (no background thread).

Comment: You can wait for a background thread using `await` too. So if you should use `Task.Run` depends if the operation is CPU or I/O bound. Whether to use async/await depends on the control flow. If you want to yield back control to the caller of the method you use `await`. Asynchronous is not really parallel in terms of threading, but the opposite of synchronously where the caller is blocked until the synchronous method has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is it necessary to change Task.Run to async/await form?

No, if you don't care about any return value from the task, you don't have to to await it. You could just set `IsWorking` to `false` to let the thread finish *eventually*.

If you want to be able to determine *when* it has finished, you should keep a reference to the `Task` and await it.

If you want to run something on a background thread "forever" or for a very long time, you should either create a `Thread` or use the overload of `Task.Factory.StartNew` that accepts a `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ... }, 
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

This gives the TPL a hint to run your action on a dedicated thread rather than "stealing" one from the thread pool.